# Retrieve a value without Hard coding the id name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Goal:
Retrieve the value from the input box instead of hard coding the text "item2" in javascript.

Problem:
Is it possible to do it? If yes, how?

> https://jsfiddle.net/2q7fwvq2/2/

```html
<p>Example list:</p>

<input id="test" value="item2">
    
    
<ul><li id="item1">Coffee (first li)</li><li id="item2">Tea (second li)</li></ul>

<p>Click the button to get the HTML content of the previous sibling of the second list item.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> Whitespace inside elements is considered as text, and text 
is considered as nodes.</p>

<p>If you add whitespace between the two li elements, the result will be "undefined".</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("item2").previousSibling.innerHTML; 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
 </script>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2q7fwvq2/1/ like this?

Comment: Yeah, difficult to understand.

Comment: You don't have to use an id, but you have to have a definition of what you what. What is that definition?

Comment: It's unclear currently what element you are trying to extract, is it the second li in a ul? Or the li which contains certain text?

Comment: It is the the value "item2" from the "input"

Comment: It is the first value of LI by retrieving the value from the input.

Comment: Have you tried getting the input value like this: `$('input').val()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access you input tag with its class name as well as you can get it as the 1st input tag of your html with javascript like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
```

and with jQuery:

```
$("input").first().val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the input tag with the given id:

```
var x = document.getElementById(document.getElementById('test').value).innerHTML;
```

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById(document.getElementById('test').value).innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<input id="test" value="item2">
<ul>
    <li id="item1">Coffee (first li)</li>
    <li id="item2">Tea (second li)</li>
    <li id="item3">Chai (third li)</li>
</ul>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```